# Conditional statement using 2 input values

Tags: jquery

im trying to figure out how to do the following :

Trying to achieve a conditional statement that just isnt working out...i have no idea where i've gone wrong!

This is the code i have so far :

```
if ($('input[name="step_2]:checked').val() == "yes" && ('input[name="step_3"]:checked').val() == "annually") {
step2_price = 30;
}
```

Comment: Presumably the typo - omission of the `$` - isn't present in the original code: `('input[name="step_3"]:checked').val()`? Also, and essentially, in what way is your conditional statement not working out? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What error message(s) did you get? What's your [mcve] code, when does/should this code run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refactored code

```
if ($('input[name="step_2"]:checked').val() == "yes" && $('input[name="step_3"]:checked').val() == "annually") {
step2_price = 30;
}
```

you missed one dollar `$` sign before `step_3` input and one `"` before `step_2`